# AWSでのMYSQLのデータ移行の際、インポート時にエラーが発生した

Tags: mysql, aws

### 前提・実現したいこと

AWSのガイドラインに基づき、WordPressを活用したWEBサイト構築を行っております。

以下がガイドラインのURLです。
https://aws.amazon.com/jp/getting-started/projects/scalable-wordpress-website/#phase5

そして、
ガイドラインのフェーズ2-4(MySQLのデータ移行)のステップ2(MySQL のデータをエクスポート)にて、
実行中にエラーメッセージが発生しました。※実際エラーが発生した工程はインポート

ちなみに、こちらの作業工程のご説明において、AWSとWordPressの連携が終わり、
SQLのデータを移行する為、Tera Termを使用してSQLデータをエクスポート後、インポートしている所です。

エラーが発生したガイドラインのページ
https://aws.amazon.com/jp/getting-started/projects/scalable-wordpress-website/02/04/

### 実行内容

$ mysql -u admin -p -h メモした RDS Endpoint のホスト名部分 wordpress < export.sql
Enter password: 指定した RDS の管理者パスワード

### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '〇〇〇'@'〇〇.〇.〇.〇〇' (using password: YES)

### 試したこと

adminをrootにて実行。
フェーズ2-4(MySQLのデータ移行)のステップ1から再度実行。

### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

ステップ 1: MySQL のデータをエクスポートにて、
↓↓
$ mysqldump -u root -p wordpress > export.sql
Enter password: 指定した MySQL の管理者パスワード

を実行した際、何もメッセージが表示されていなかったので、
本当にexport.sqlにエクスポートされているかわかりませんでした。
仮にエクスポートされていなかった場合、今回のエラーに関係があるのでしょうか?

AWS初心者で初歩的なご質問だとは思いますが、どなたかご回答のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: エラーメッセージが全てだと思います。MySQLはユーザとアクセス元で権限を変えることができるので実行したIPからのadminというuserのアクセスでは権限が与えられてないんだと思います。コマンドの詳細は忘れたので回答ではなくコメントにしますが mysql  grant とかでしらべてみればユーザにIPからの権限を付加できると思います

Comment: RDSインスタンスの「マスターユーザー」と「マスターパスワード」が一致していればログインできるはずですけどね。マスターユーザが間違っていないか確認して、あっていればパスワードをリセットしてみたらどうでしょうか。

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。また、再度1点質問があります。いろいろ試した上、ホスト名が原因だとわかったのですが、いくらホスト名を確認しても間違いはないように感じております。また、ホスト名は手順書通りRDSのエンドポイントを参照しております。つきましてはこの問題の解決策をご教示いただきたいです。どなたかご回答のほどよろしくお願いいたします。